# Object declaring c++

Tags: c++

***Upon request I have post the rest of the [code in idone.com](http://ideone.com/JiVXt)***

So I have to create my own Vector Class and I did. It is required.
When I implement it in another class however, It gives me [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHtHg.png)
This is how I am trying to implement it:

```
#include "Vector.h"

class UserDB
{
private:
    Vector<AccountInfo*> _accounts;
//more code that previous to this implementation worked fine.
};
```

I was hoping someone could tell me what to do about it. I'm completely clueless in this one. Java never gave such errors, whatsoever...
EDIT: I have also realized that when I say something like `Vector<int> _accounts;` it runs completely fine, however when done with a class such as Vector, it seems almost impossible to fix it. I am reading a lot, but I still cannot seem to find a fix to this.

This is my Vector Header

```
#include "ArrayClass.h" //Class with more methods
#include "AbstractVector.h" //Another class with more method
template <class DT>
class Vector: virtual public ArrayClass<DT>,
virtual public AbstractVector<DT>
{
protected:
int _currSize;
int _incFactor;
public:
Vector ();
Vector (int n);
Vector (int n, DT& val);
Vector (const Vector<DT>& v);
Vector (const ArrayClass<DT>& ac);
virtual ~Vector();
void operator= (const Vector<DT>& v);
void operator= (const ArrayClass<DT>& ac);
virtual void insert (const DT& item, int index);
virtual void remove (int index);
virtual void add (const DT& item);
virtual int size() const;
virtual int capacity() const;
virtual int incFactor() const;
virtual void setIncFactor(int f);
void setCapacity(int c);
};
```

And this one is the Actual code Vector.cpp

```
#include "Vector.h"

template <class DT>
Vector<DT>::Vector () : ArrayClass<DT>()
{
    _currSize = 0;
    _incFactor = 5;
}
Vector<DT>::~Vector ()
{
_currSize = NULL;
_incFactor = NULL;
}
template <class DT>
Vector<DT>::Vector (int n): ArrayClass<DT>(n)
{
    _currSize = 0;
    _incFactor = (n+1)/2;
}
template <class DT>
Vector<DT>::Vector (int n, DT& val)
    : ArrayClass<DT>(n, val)
{
    _currSize = 0;
    _incFactor = n/2;
}
template <class DT>
Vector<DT>::Vector (const Vector<DT>&v)
    : ArrayClass<DT> (v)
{
    _currSize = v._currSize;
    _incFactor = v.incFactor();
}
template <class DT>
Vector<DT>::Vector (const ArrayClass<DT>& ac)
    : ArrayClass<DT> (ac)
{
    _currSize = ac.size();
    _incFactor = (_currSize+1)/2;
}
template <class DT>
void Vector<DT>::operator= (const Vector<DT>& v)
{
    ArrayClass<DT>::copy (v);
    _currSize = v._currSize;
    _incFactor = v.incFactor();
}
//template <class DT>
//void Vector<DT>::operator= (const ArrayClass<DT>&ac)
//{
//  ArrayClass<DT>::copy (ac);
//  _currSize = ac.size();
//  _incFactor = (_currSize+1)/2;
//}
template <class DT>
int Vector<DT>::size() const
{
    return _currSize;
}
template <class DT>
int Vector<DT>::capacity() const
{
    return _size;
}
template <class DT>
int Vector<DT>::incFactor() const
{
    return _incFactor;
}
template <class DT>
void Vector<DT>::add (const DT& item)
{
    insert (item, _currSize);
}
template <class DT>
void Vector<DT>::setIncFactor(int f)
{
    if (f >= 0) _incFactor = f;
}
template <class DT>
void Vector<DT>::setCapacity(int c)
{
    int len = _currSize;
    if (len > c) len = c;
    DT* paNew = new DT[c];
    if (paNew == NULL)
    {
        throw ArrayMemoryException();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        paNew[i] = paObject[i];
    }
    if (paObject != NULL)
    {
        delete[] paObject;
    }
    paObject = paNew;
    _size = c;
    if (_currSize > len)
    {
        _currSize = len;
    }
}
template <class DT>
void Vector<DT>::insert (const DT& item, int index)
{
if ((index < 0) || (index > _currSize))
{
throw ArrayBoundsException();
}
if (_currSize+1 == _size)
{
setCapacity (_size + _incFactor);
}
_currSize++;
for (int i = _currSize-1; i > index; i--)
{
(*this)[i] = (*this)[i-1];
}
(*this)[index] = item;
}
template <class DT>
void Vector<DT>::remove (int index)
{
if ((index < 0) || (index >= _currSize))
{
throw ArrayBoundsException();
}
if (_currSize <= _size-_incFactor)
{
setCapacity (_size - _incFactor);
}
for (int i = index; i < _currSize-1; i++)
{
(*this)[i] = (*this)[i+1];
}
_currSize--;
}
```

Comment: let me guess, you put the definition of your vectors member functions in a .cxx file?

Comment: What do you have in `Vector.h`?

Comment: Is your Vector class marked public?  It in the same project or a separate project?

Comment: Nope. Vector.h for headers and Vector.cpp for the actual code in it.

Comment: Post your Vector.h and Vector.cpp files, or at least the first 20-30 lines of each.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: more looks like the cpp is not included in the linkage...

Comment: @DStanley Uh... I will try to make it public and see how it goes, although I was never encouraged to make classes public or private in C++

Comment: Is it me or do the errors have nothing to do with this source? I mean, the errors are about class `AccountInfo`...

Comment: @MrLister : the OP explained it: "When I implement it **in another class** however, It gives me these errors"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include .cpp file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836871/include-cpp-file)

Comment: @MooingDuck Saw it, but I thought it would be a good idea to post mine anyway since the problem and solution to that post were different than what I could apply to mine

Comment: At the point, where template is being instantiated, template definition should be in scope. Because compiler uses that definition to generate a new class ( with given template argument). So, this implies, the template should be defined in a header file.

Comment: @Yokhen: Check again, the first answer to that question is _exactly_ how to solve your issue (as are, I expect, all the other answers).

Comment: @fizzbuzz If you can see (or maybe I am getting blind) the template `template <DT>` is declared everytime; for the class as well as for the methods....

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: Its a template, you can not have the definition of its functions in a seperate TU and just link that, it has to be available at instantiation time.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: good point, more about it for the curious [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12).

Comment: @PlasmaHH are you saying I should put everything in a .cpp file (Vector.cpp)? And if that is the case, how can I `#include` it? C++ will only let me to include headers (i.e. `#include "Vector.h"`). How can I work it out? I'm getting desperate.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov I just started reading this, I hope this can fix my problem. It looks very similar to what I am experiencing. Will be reporting back when I'm done trying to fix it.

Comment: If this conversation needs to be continued, please take it to a chat-room. Thanks!

Comment: @Yokhen: no, you should put everythign in the .h file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While compiling your code, at the point, where template is being instantiated, i.e. in your code

```
Vector<AccountInfo*> _accounts;
```

the compiler will generate a new class using template `Vector` ( with given template argument i.e `AccountInfo*`). Thus compiler needs access to implementation of template `Vector<T>` at this point.

So, this implies, the template `Vector<T>` should be completely implemented in a header file.

If you do want to keep the separation between template definition and implementation then
  you can have two header files, one `Vector.h` and other `Vector_impl.h`, with `Vector_impl.h` containing the implementation of the template.

Include `Vector.h` in the `Vector_impl.h` and Include `Vector_impl.h` in the .cpp file where you are instantiating the template i.e.  `Vector < AccountInfo*>.`

Comment: I am a little confused. What about the "template `Vector`" exactly should I "implement" to fix the problem? Do you mean to put the contents of Vector.cpp in Vector.h?

Comment: @Yokhen, you should understand, a template is only used to generate other classes. If a template is not used i.e not instantiated at any place in your code, then no code is generated for that template. Therefore, a template implementation should be "#included" in the file where you are instantiating it.

Comment: So, just removed the Vector.cpp file and added its contents to Vector.h and I'm getting the same errors [with different content...](http://i.imgur.com/o6IbB.png)

Comment: @Yokhen : are you sure the constructor for ArrayClass is defined too?

Comment: @Yokhen If possible post ArrayClass.h and Abstractvector.h or any other files , we might need to compile your code. You can use http://codepad.org/  or http://pastebin.com/ or http://ideone.com/

Comment: @victor yes I did sir. I will fix it now in the question.

Comment: @fizzbuzz Just updated it on that. Normally if I posted all of it, everyone would be mad and would get downvoted, so that's why I didn't upload it everything at once.

Comment: @Yokhen your uploaded code compiles after some rearrangement and some minor modifications and most importantly after defining the destructor  for ArrayClass. Check it out here http://ideone.com/ngViq

Comment: Man, thank you very much! That was very helpful :D Now I get it!

Answer (score 2):

these errors are here because the link phase (which takes place after the compile phase) couldn’t find the binary code for the constructor and destructor of Vector and the destructor of ArrayClass.

My guess is that you forgot to define those function in the template class, but you declared them. It compiled before because you did not actually instantiate an object of that class (my guess). The easy solution (assuming my guess is correct) is to put the method definitions in the same file as the declarations (i.e. Vector.h). Could you show what’s in "Vector.h"?

Last remark: the "private" keyword is useless here, class are private by default.

**EDIT**: 
To extend my remark, your code is actually missing a definition for `Vector::~Vector`. Java did not complain about it because destructors don’t exist there :)

Comment: About your last remark: being explicit is rarely a bad thing.

Comment: I’m not entirely satisfied though. I can’t figure the reason why the first error popped.

Comment: The first error was because the `Vector<class AccountInfo*>::Vector<class AccountInfo*>(void)` constructor was not instantiated in any translation unit, and thus the symbol could not be linked.  It was not instantiated, because no TU had both the template function definition, _and_ the type to instantiate with, because the template function definition was in it's own cpp file.

Comment: So I added a Destructor a while ago and the problem persists.