# Including .cpp files

Tags: c++

I have read in places like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836871/include-cpp-file?rq=1) that you have to include .h files and not .cpp files, because otherwise then you get an error. So for example

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foop.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int x=42;
std::cout << x <<std::endl;
std::cout << foo(x) << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

foop.h

```
#ifndef FOOP_H
#define FOOP_H
int foo(int a);
#endif
```

foop.cpp

```
int foo(int a){
    return ++a;
}
```

works, but if I replace `#include "foop.h"` with `#include "foop.cpp"` I get an error (Using Dev C++ 4.9.9.2, Windows):

```
multiple definition of foo(int)
first defined here
```

Why is this?

Comment: This example should compile fine. Are there any missing details?

Comment: Are you ONLY including the .cpp? That should be allowed in this simple case. Including both .h and .cpp obvisouly multiply defines the fucntion

Answer (score 78, accepted):

What `include` does is copying all the contents from the file (which is the argument inside the `<>` or the `""` ), so when the preproccesor finishes its work `main.cpp` will look like:

```
// iostream stuff

int foo(int a){
    return ++a;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int x=42;
   std::cout << x <<std::endl;
   std::cout << foo(x) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

So foo will be defined in `main.cpp`, but a definition also exists in `foop.cpp`, so the compiler "gets confused" because of the function duplication.

Comment: I suppose you could work around it by using `#pragma once` directives.

Comment: @xorguy how does foop.c and foop.h knows about each other? I understand what you are saying in your answer but it is still unclear to me how does main.cpp knows about definition of foo? main.cpp includes foop.h whare is only declaration not definition of foo. So how does main.cpp knows about definition of foo?

Comment: @WakanTanka If done the correct way (i.e. including the header file), `main.cpp` does *not* know about `foo.cpp`, and therfore does not throw an error. This is why we use header files. In his answer, @xorguy used an example where `main.cpp` is #including the cpp file instead. In this case, because the same function end up getting defined in both `main.cpp` and `foo.cpp`, an error is thrown.

Comment: Compiler will remain happy, it is linker which will show an error about duplicate implementation. At the same time if you exclude foo.cpp from linking - the build will succeed even without `#pragma once`. But it is waste of compiler time to do this way in big projects, because all code will recompile on any change.

Answer (score 47):

There are many reasons to discourage including a .cpp file, but it isn't strictly disallowed. Your example should compile fine.

The problem is probably that you're compiling both main.cpp and foop.cpp, which means two copies of foop.cpp are being linked together. The linker is complaining about the duplication.

Answer (score 25):

When you say `#include "foop.cpp"`, it is as if you had copied the entire contents of `foop.cpp` and pasted it into `main.cpp`.

So when you compile `main.cpp`, the compiler emits a `main.obj` that contains the executable code for two functions: `main` and `foo`.

When you compile `foop.cpp` itself, the compiler emits a `foop.obj` that contains the executable code for function `foo`.

When you link them together, the compiler sees two definitions for function `foo` (one from `main.obj` and the other from `foop.obj`) and complains that you have multiple definitions.

Answer (score 11):

You should just include header file(s).

If you include header file, header file automatically finds .cpp file.
 --> This process is done by LINKER.

Comment: This answer perfectly explains the problem addressed in the question.

Comment: @pasha this answer perfectly misses nuances of this topic while being factually wrong at the same time.

Comment: @enedil thanks for pointing that out, after spending time on google i agree now, but please do explain why it is, may be i could learn some other things

Comment: @pasha  I used to read this answer and thought it was right too... It is so wrong and kinda misleading. There is no such "header file find .cpp file" thing. Because only .cpp files get compiled. Header files merely stay there and wait some source files to inlcude them. Check this video to learn more https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tIqpEmWMLI

Comment: @Rick Thanks for the link

Answer (score 8):

This boils down to a difference between *definitions* and *declarations*.

- You can declare functions and variables multiple times, in different translation units, or in the same translation unit. Once you declare a function or a variable, you can use it from that point on.
- You can define a non-static function or a variable only once in all of your translation units. Defining non-static items more than once causes linker errors.

Headers generally contain declarations; cpp files contain definitions. When you include a file with definitions more than once, you get duplicates during linking.

In your situation one defintion comes from `foo.cpp`, and the other definition comes from `main.cpp`, which includes `foo.cpp`.

**Note:** if you change `foo` to be `static`, you would have no linking errors. Despite the lack of errors, this is *not* a good thing to do.

Comment: This is almost the answer I was looking for. I'm literally new in C++, so how do I declare a class, for example? Should I use a header file? Then how do I define that class to be used in another files? Sorry for this question, unrelated, but I don't find appropriate help :(

Comment: @TheProHands [Take a look at this article](https://www.gamedev.net/resources/_/technical/general-programming/organizing-code-files-in-c-and-c-r1798).

Answer (score 2):

Because of the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) (probably<sup>1</sup>).

In C++, each non-inline object and function must have exactly *one* definition within the program.  By `#include`ing the file in which `foo(int)` is defined (the CPP file), it is defined both in every file where foop.cpp is `#include`d, and in foop.cpp itself (assuming foop.cpp is compiled).

You can make a function `inline` to override this behavior, but I'm not recommending that here.  I have never seen a situation where it is necessary or even desirable to `#include` a CPP file.

There are situations where it is desireable to include a definition of something.  This is specially true when you try to seperate the definition of a template from the declaration of it.  In those cases, I name the file HPP rather than CPP to denote the difference.

---

<sup>1</sup>: "(probably)"  I say probably here because the actual code you've posted should compile without errors, but given the compiler error it seems likely that the code you posted isn't *exactly* the same as the code you're compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Because your program now contains two copies of the `foo` function, once inside foo.cpp and once inside main.cpp

Think of #include as an instruction to the compiler to copy/paste the contents of that file into your code, so you'll end up with a processed main.cpp that looks like this

```
#include <iostream> // actually you'll get the contents of the iostream header here, but I'm not going to include it!
int foo(int a){
    return ++a;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int x=42;
std::cout << x <<std::endl;
std::cout << foo(x) << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

and foo.cpp

```
int foo(int a){
    return ++a;
}
```

hence the multiple definition error

Comment: Inside the `main.cpp`, there is **NO foo() defined** and `foo()` is defined inside the `foop.cpp` file. When we `#include<foop.cpp>`, why is `foo()` getting included twice when code inside `foop.cpp` is getting pasted inside the `main.cpp` file only **once**?

Answer (score 0):

So I found that if you are compiling from Visual Studios you just have to exclude the included .cpp file from the final build (that which you are extending from):

> Visual Studios: .cpp file > right click  > properties > configuration properties >
>   general > excluded from build > **yes**

I believe you can also exclude the file when compiling from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I want to clarify something: including header files is not neccessary to make the linker understand what you want. You can just declare it and it will be linked fine.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream.h>
//not including "foop.cpp"!

int foo(int a);

int main(){
  std::cout << foo(4) << std::endln;
}
```

foop.cpp:

```
int foo(int a){
  return a++;
}
```

I don't encourage doing like this, but know that headers are not some magic which you have to follow to make the code compile.

Answer (score -3):

Using ".h" method is better
But if you really want to include the .cpp file then make foo(int) static in foo.cpp