# sharing global variables across multiple .cpp files (visual studio 2015)

Tags: c++, header, include, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing a program (c++) in visual studio with multiple functions which I would like to spread across multiple .cpp files.  I originally had all functions (the entire program) contained within one .cpp file and it was working fine, but now as I try to break it up I am running into all sorts of errors.

I have some global variables which I originally defined just at the top of the single .cpp file, but now as I move some functions, which use these constant variables, into separate .cpp files I get errors.

How can I share these constant variables across multiple .cpp files?  Should I create a header file that contains all the constant global variables and then reference them somehow in each .cpp file in which they are used?

Also, as some of the functions I have written call upon other functions which I have also written, how can I split these functions into separate .cpp files and have everything still work?  Should I prototype all necessary functions in each .cpp file in which I would like to call them?

Here is the general format which I would like to make work:

main.cpp file:

```
int main()
{
//calling functions such as minimax(),  printBoard(), and others
//using global variables such as const in w_ or const int pDisc
}
```

minimax.cpp file:

```
void minimax()
{
//code for minimax function
//minimax () calls other functions such as winDetect() and playMove()
//using global variables such as const in w_ or const int pDisc
}
```

helper_func.cpp file:

```
winDetect(){//definition}
playMove(){//definition}
printBoard(){//definition}
//using global variables such as const in w_ or const int pDisc
```

I also have the following header files which I would like to include in each .cpp file (not sure if I need to just copy and paste these into each .cpp file or if there's a way to include them globally):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
```

Thanks in advance for any help! If any more info on how I've organized the program is needed, please let me know!

EDIT:

I tried setting up a header file (called con4.h), but I'm getting an error on every function declaration in con4.h that says "expression must have a constant value".  For some declarations, the error gets thrown more than once.  Here's the full code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#ifndef CON4_H
#define CON4_H

//pDisc =  disc; cDisc = computer disc; nDisc = no disc
const int pDisc = 1, cDisc = 2, nDisc = 0;
//width and height variables
const int w_ = 7, h_ = 6;
//Base number of maximum iterations (depending on the stage in the game, recursion may go more or less deep)
const int MAX_ITER = 7;


//Values for SetConsoleTextAttribute()
HANDLE H = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

const int BLACK = 0;
const int BLUE = 1;
const int GREEN = 2;
const int CYAN = 3;
const int RED = 4;
const int MAGENTA = 5;
const int BROWN = 6;
const int LIGHTGRAY = 7;
const int DARKGRAY = 8;
const int LIGHTBLUE = 9;
const int LIGHTGREEN = 10;
const int LIGHTCYAN = 11;
const int LIGHTRED = 12;
const int LIGHTMAGENTA = 13;
const int YELLOW = 14;
const int WHITE = 15;

//Declarations (but not definitions) for all functions

#endif
```

Comment: @EdHeal: Shouldn't*?

Comment: Opps . Sorry. Hate this predicted text

Comment: You shouldn't have usedone global variables in the first place. Take the opportunity to remove them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I create a header file that contains all the constant global
>   variables and then reference them somehow in each .cpp file in which
>   they are used?

yes.please do that.consider using namespaces too to group them.

> Also, as some of the functions I have written call upon other
>   functions which I have also written, how can I split these functions
>   into separate .cpp files and have everything still work?

Generally, the norm is to  start designing a program by dividing the problem into easily managed sections. Each of these sections might be implemented as one or more functions. All functions from each section usually live in a single file.

Say, in your case:

```
//board.h

void printBoard(int board[][w_]);
void copyBoard(int board[][w_], int newBoard[][w_]);

//color.h

void printColor(string str, int color);
void printColor(int i, int color);
void printColor(char c, int color);

//algo.h

bool playMove(int board[][w_], int col, int who);
bool winDetect(int board[][w_], int who);
void minimax(int board[][w_], int score[], int who, int currentCheck, int iter);


//main.cpp
//include all header files and combine the logic
```

In object oriented terms, you can implement the above logic by creating board, color and algo classes and then combining the logic.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I understand how to go about doing this.  I'll try it out and post results

Answer (score 0):

You shoul include in header a file with .h extension, this mean will copy your code from your cpp file and put in main file.

Please take a look here [c++ including .cpp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547091/including-cpp-files)