# Compilation is successful even if function definition is missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, include, c-preprocessor

I've borrowed example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547091/including-cpp-files) question. There are following files:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foop.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int x=42;
std::cout << x <<std::endl;
std::cout << foo(x) << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

**foop.h**

```
#ifndef FOOP_H
#define FOOP_H
int foo(int a);
#endif
```

**foop.cpp**

```
int foo(int a){
    return ++a;
}
```

As you can see `main.cpp` includes `foop.h`, but `foop.h` contains only declaration not definition of function `foo`. How does `main.cpp` knows about existence of `foop.cpp` and the definition of `foo` function? My first guess was that if the name of `*.h` is the same as of `*.cpp` then it somehow magically works, but it also worked when I've renamed `foop.cpp` to `foop2.cpp`

PS: I keep files under one project, inside same directory inside Visual Studio

PPS: Can I somehow debug the compilation process so I can see what is going on?

Comment: One question per question please, makes it easier to write concise answers or find appropriate dupes if applicable.

Comment: `I keep files under one project,` - This is the important part. An MSVC++ project simply is a group of files that (once compiled) should be linked together. With files in separate projects, you need to make one project a library project and tell the other project to use that first project.

Comment: @MSalters thank you, this should be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler *doesn't* need to know about the definition.  That's the linker's job.

Comment: If I understand correct then when I run build in Visual Studio then compiler compiles all files (if they are syntactically correct, even if they are only function definition without main()) inside project and then linker adds them together by using techniques (symbol tables) mentioned in duplicate question?