Problem with Cmake and including third-party library
I'm trying to properly configure Cmake for my CUDA project. I'm using  third party library, CGBN: https://github.com/NVlabs/CGBN/tree/master and Catch2 for unit-tests.
Basically I am trying to build two targets: main and tests.
The problem is when I try to compile more than one source file for target, which includes header file which includes this CGBN header file I got multiple definition error during build.
Examples in the CGBN library use this command in Makefiles:
nvcc $(INC) $(LIB) -I../../include -arch=sm_70 modinv_odd_faster.cu -o mo_faster -lgmp
so I used target_include_directories to map -I flag from Makefile to my Cmake.
Example:
add_executable(
tests
tests/test_add_points_ECC79p.cu -> includes header file main.cuh which itself includes cgbn
src/main.cu -> includes main.cuh too
).

Complete Cmake configuration:
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
    project(cuda-rho-pollard CUDA)
    
    # General
    set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 17)
    set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 75)
    
    # MAIN
    add_executable(main
            src/main.cu
            src/test.cu
    )
    # set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
    
    # CGBN
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE gmp)
    target_include_directories(main PRIVATE include/CGBN/include)
    
    # TESTS
    find_package(Catch2 3 REQUIRED)
    
    add_executable(
            tests
            tests/test_add_points_ECC79p.cu
            src/main.cu
            )
    target_compile_definitions(tests PRIVATE UNIT_TESTING)
    
    # CGBN
    target_link_libraries(tests PRIVATE gmp)
    target_include_directories(tests PRIVATE include/CGBN/include)
    
    set_target_properties(tests PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
    set_target_properties(tests PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CUDA)
    target_link_libraries(tests PRIVATE Catch2::Catch2WithMain)
    
    include(CTest)
    include(Catch)
    catch_discover_tests(tests)

The error message I got:
[main] Building folder: /home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/build tests
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/build --config Debug --target tests --
[build] [2/4  25% :: 1.897] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/tests.dir/tests/test_add_points_ECC79p.cu.o
[build] [2/4  50% :: 4.417] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/tests.dir/src/main.cu.o
[build] [3/4  75% :: 4.487] Linking CUDA executable CMakeFiles/tests.dir/cmake_device_link.o
[build] [4/4 100% :: 4.686] Linking CUDA executable tests
[build] FAILED: tests tests-b12d07c_tests.cmake /home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/build/tests-b12d07c_tests.cmake 
[build] : && /usr/bin/g++  CMakeFiles/tests.dir/tests/test_add_points_ECC79p.cu.o CMakeFiles/tests.dir/src/main.cu.o CMakeFiles/tests.dir/cmake_device_link.o -o tests  -lgmp  /usr/lib64/libCatch2Main.a  /usr/lib64/libCatch2.a  -lcudadevrt  -lcudart_static  -lrt  -lpthread  -ldl -L"/usr/local/cuda-12.4/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/stubs" -L"/usr/local/cuda-12.4/targets/x86_64-linux/lib" && cd /home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/build && /usr/bin/cmake -D TEST_TARGET=tests -D TEST_EXECUTABLE=/home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/build/tests -D TEST_EXECUTOR= -D TEST_WORKING_DIR=/home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/build -D TEST_SPEC= -D TEST_EXTRA_ARGS= -D TEST_PROPERTIES= -D TEST_PREFIX= -D TEST_SUFFIX= -D TEST_LIST=tests_TESTS -D TEST_REPORTER= -D TEST_OUTPUT_DIR= -D TEST_OUTPUT_PREFIX= -D TEST_OUTPUT_SUFFIX= -D TEST_DL_PATHS= -D CTEST_FILE=/home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/build/tests-b12d07c_tests.cmake -P /usr/lib64/cmake/Catch2/CatchAddTests.cmake
[build] /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/13/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/tests.dir/src/main.cu.o: in function `cgbn_error_report_alloc(cgbn_error_report_t**)':
[build] /home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/include/CGBN/include/cgbn/cgbn.cu:25: multiple definition of `cgbn_error_report_alloc(cgbn_error_report_t**)'; CMakeFiles/tests.dir/tests/test_add_points_ECC79p.cu.o:/home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/include/CGBN/include/cgbn/cgbn.cu:25: first defined here
[build] /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/13/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/tests.dir/src/main.cu.o: in function `cgbn_error_report_free(cgbn_error_report_t*)':
[build] /home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/include/CGBN/include/cgbn/cgbn.cu:42: multiple definition of `cgbn_error_report_free(cgbn_error_report_t*)'; CMakeFiles/tests.dir/tests/test_add_points_ECC79p.cu.o:/home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/include/CGBN/include/cgbn/cgbn.cu:42: first defined here
[build] /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/13/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/tests.dir/src/main.cu.o: in function `cgbn_error_report_check(cgbn_error_report_t*)':
[build] /home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/include/CGBN/include/cgbn/cgbn.cu:46: multiple definition of `cgbn_error_report_check(cgbn_error_report_t*)'; CMakeFiles/tests.dir/tests/test_add_points_ECC79p.cu.o:/home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/include/CGBN/include/cgbn/cgbn.cu:46: first defined here
[build] /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/13/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/tests.dir/src/main.cu.o: in function `cgbn_error_report_reset(cgbn_error_report_t*)':
[build] /home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/include/CGBN/include/cgbn/cgbn.cu:50: multiple definition of `cgbn_error_report_reset(cgbn_error_report_t*)'; CMakeFiles/tests.dir/tests/test_add_points_ECC79p.cu.o:/home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/include/CGBN/include/cgbn/cgbn.cu:50: first defined here
[build] /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/13/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/tests.dir/src/main.cu.o: in function `cgbn_error_string(cgbn_error_report_t*)':
[build] /home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/include/CGBN/include/cgbn/cgbn.cu:61: multiple definition of `cgbn_error_string(cgbn_error_report_t*)'; CMakeFiles/tests.dir/tests/test_add_points_ECC79p.cu.o:/home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/include/CGBN/include/cgbn/cgbn.cu:61: first defined here
[build] /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/13/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/tests.dir/src/main.cu.o: in function `cgbn_check(cgbn_error_report_t*, char const*, int)':
[build] /home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/src/main.cuh:15: multiple definition of `cgbn_check(cgbn_error_report_t*, char const*, int)'; CMakeFiles/tests.dir/tests/test_add_points_ECC79p.cu.o:/home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/tests/../src/main.cuh:15: first defined here
[build] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[proc] The command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/atlomak/PROJECTS/inz/thesis/build --config Debug --target tests -- exited with code: 1
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:04.708
[build] Build finished with exit code 1

Repo for project for reference: project
I don't have any more ideas on how to deal with this issue. How to do it right?
The only way to compile tests target, was to directly include the src/main.cu file in tests/test_add_points_ECC79p.cu. But I assume it's not the right way either.
I am not very experienced with Cmake/C/Cuda (In my day job I mainly deal with Go and Python).
Will appreciate any help.
I tried compiling sources from the library as add_library and then including just one header file, but got compilation errors too. I don't think it's the proper way, because it's forces me to look through all source files in library and de facto create build script for it.

You really need to quote the error message you get. It's hard to fix errors when you cannot see the error message. Also it seems quite likely to me that the error is in your code, not in your cmake file. So show the code that relates to the error message you get.

Since you are not experinced with C (or C++) I would guess that the problem is that you don't know the correct way to declare and define global variables when you have multiple source files. But I'm only guessing, more information is needed.

Where is the error message? Please copy text with report what went wrong. My first guess is that you are importing CGBN in wrong way.

@MarekR I supplied error message in the post.

unfortunately I could not test your code since my computer environment does not support CUDA, however I see that your error messages says that your linker complains that you are redefining functions in some unsupported way. So I would try get around that issue by guarding the redefined functions inside namespaces as on this example code:
#include <iostream>
#include <glibmm/value.h>

class A {
        public: 
                void test_message(){
                std::cout << "hello from global A" << std::endl;
                }
};

namespace redefineme {
        class A{
                public: 
                        void test_message(){
                                std::cout << "hello from scoped A" << std::endl;
                        }
        };
        class ValueBase{
                public:
                        void init(const GValue * value){
                                std::cout << "that is some other ValueBase::init" << std::endl;
                        }
        };
};

int main(){
        redefineme::A test_redefine = *(new redefineme::A());
        redefineme::ValueBase nvb = *(new redefineme::ValueBase);
        test_redefine.test_message();
        const GValue * some_value;
        nvb.init(some_value);
}


which prints hello from scoped A and that is some other ValueBase::init; run pkgconf --libs --cflags gtkmm-3.0 for getting the flags for compiling this code. More in c++ namespaces
Then from nm my compiled code here you get something like _ZN10redefineme9ValueBase4initEPK7_GValue which means now we have different symbols produced for the same name which solves the linker confusion

The functions in the question are defined in the file https://github.com/NVlabs/CGBN/blob/master/include/cgbn/cgbn.cu, which is included into two source files. C++ namespaces are absolutely unrelated to the problem.

if it gets the program built then it is related

But the redefinition error comes from the need of including the same files from library to both source files. I don't think it will help. I don't want to modify third-party library by adding namespaces

maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547091/including-cpp-files is related?

the problem may be on lines such as target_include_directories(main PRIVATE include/CGBN/include) as on include/ there are both the .cu implementation files and the header files

@jefersonlemos yes, I think the same. But is there any workaround/good practice to deal with this type of library? Can I somehow force linker to link it only once?

keep in mind that very likely it would only work for a single ld process, but on "info ld" there is a section talking about linker scripts, I dont know if there is some possibility about excluding files though, though including files is straightforward
