# Virtual methods in templates are not generated

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get “unresolved external symbol” errors when using templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456713/why-do-i-get-unresolved-external-symbol-errors-when-using-templates)

I have a little bit complicated set of classes.
Class _A which has child parametrized class A which has two children A1 and A2.
Class B. Contains pointer on object of class _A as member. Has two child classes B1 and B2 which correspond to classes A1 and A2 each. B1 constructs _A as A1. B2 as A2 respectivelly.
And finally class Y which has child BY defined inside of class B.
Now how it is present in files.

**tf1.h**

```
#include <iostream>

struct Y{ // goes to the file tf2.h as ancestor of the class B::BY
};


struct _A{ // goes to the file tf2.h as a member of the class B
};

template<class X>
struct A: public _A {  // goes to two classes below only as an ancestor
    virtual void method();
    protected:
    virtual void m() = 0;
};

template<class X>
struct A1: public A<X>{  // goes to the file tf2.h to the class B1
    protected:
    void m();
};

template<class X>
struct A2: public A<X>{  // goes to the file tf2.h to the class B2
    protected:
    void m();
};
```

**tf1.cpp**

```
#include "tf1.h"


template<class X>
void A<X>::method(){
    /* here the class X used */
    std::cout << "A::method called" << std::endl;
    m();
}

template<class X>
void A1<X>::m(){
    std::cout << "A1::m called" << std::endl;
}

template<class X>
void A2<X>::m(){
    std::cout << "A1::m called" << std::endl;
}
```

**tf2.h**

```
#include "tf1.h"

class B{   // is the counterpain of the class _A
    protected:
    class BY: public Y{
    };

    _A * mp_x;
};


class B1: public B{  // is the counterpain of the class A1
    public:
    B1(){mp_x = new A1<BY>; std::cout << "B::B is called" << std::endl;}
};

class B2: public B{  // is the counterpain of the class A2
    public:
    B2(){mp_x = new A2<BY>; std::cout << "C::C is called" << std::endl;}
};
```

**tfmain.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "tf2.h"

int main (int,char**){
    B2 b2;
    system ("PAUSE");
}
```

And, finally, the problem.

```
d:>g++ -std=c++0x tfmain.cpp -o tfmain.exe
ccB2BnSP.o:tfmain.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV2A2IN1B2BYEE[__ZTV2A2IN1B2BYEE]+0x8): undefined reference to `A<B::BY>::method()'
ccB2BnSP.o:tfmain.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV2A2IN1B2BYEE[__ZTV2A2IN1B2BYEE]+0xc): undefined reference to `A2<B::BY>::m()'
ccB2BnSP.o:tfmain.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV1AIN1B2BYEE[__ZTV1AIN1B2BYEE]+0x8): undefined reference to `A<B::BY>::method()
```

I am using MinGW v4.7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it simply, you can't put template definitions into a cpp file (there are workarounds... but not pleasant ones)

The reason is that the compiler only instantiates a template at the first point you invoke that template, since the compiler needs to know what type to instantiates the template with.

Now, if you put the template definition into a separate cpp file which gets compiled separately into its own translation unit. Where does the compiler look for cases where you instantiate the template?

For example

```
// Template.h
template <typename T>
class templateObj { ~templateObj(); };

// Template.cpp
#include "Template.h"
template <typename T>
templateObj::~templateObj() { /* delete stuff! */ }

// YourFile.cpp
#include "Template.h"
templateObj<int> myObj;
```

Now, when the compiler compiles this code.
It will generate two translation units, one for `Template.cpp`, the other for `YourFile.cpp`.

Note that `Template.cpp` has not a single clue of what `YourFile.cpp` is and what's inside it. So it has no way of knowning that in `YourFile.cpp`, you have used `templateObj` with a template parameter type `int`. Because of this, in the resulting translation unit of `Template.cpp`, the compiler will **not** generate an instantiated version of the destructor of `templateObj`

Now, let's look at `YourFile.cpp`, when the compiler sees that you're instantiating `templateObj` with type `int`, it goes to look for the definition of `templateObj`. Since you have included `Template.h`, the compiler sees that you have declared a destructor for `templateObj`. But where is the definiton??

The compiler doesnt see the definition of `~templateObj()`, nor does it know where to look for at this point.
So it simply holds off and will pass on to the linker to search for the correct module to link to.

Now here is the problem:

In the two translation units the compiler has just produced, neither `YourFile.o` or `Template.o` has the definition for `template<int>::~template()`.
The linker reads in `YourFile.o` and expects to have that version of the destructor of `templateObj` to link to, but the only other translation unit `Template.o` doesn't have it; in fact, it has **nothing**.

So what now? The linker has to complain... and that's the error message you get.

---

A bit more details about what happened with your code:

- Two translation units are produced: `tf1.o` and `tfmain.o`
- `tf1.o` is generated from `tf1.cpp` and whatever it includes.
- `tfmain.o` is generated from `tfmain.cpp` and whatever itcludes.

So what do they include? What does `tf1.cpp` and `tfmain.cpp` know about the rest of the code?

`tf1.cpp`

- `#include "tf1.h"` ==> which `#include <iostream>`...

`tfmain.cpp`

- `#include "tf2.h"` ==> which `#include "tf1.h"` ==> which `#include <iostream>`...

What does `tf1.cpp` have? What does it know?

- *knows* **declarations** of `Y` and `_A`
- *knows* template **declarations** of `A`, `A1` and `A2`
- *has* template **definitions** for various methods in `A`, `A1`, and `A2`

What does `tfmain.cpp` have? What does it know?

- *knows* **declarations** of `B`, `B1`, `B2`, `Y` and `_A`
- *knows* template **declarations** of `A`, `A1` and `A2`
- *has* **definitions** for various methods in `B`, `B1`, `B2`
- *has* `main` and an instance of `B2`

So, now the questions are:

#### Does `tf1.cpp` know anything about `tf2.h` or `tfmain.cpp`? Does it know that you're creating an instance to `B2` which instantiates `A2` with type `BY`?

#### Does `tfmain.cpp` know anything about `tf1.cpp`? Does it know the **definitions** of methods in `A`, `A1` or `A2`??

They do **NOT** know each other, and thus the compiler has no way to generate the code for the definiton to your template classes in the translation unit `tf1.o` (At that point, it doesn't even know you're creating an instance to B2 which instantiates `A2` with type `BY`).

And finally the linker has no way to find the code `tfmain.o` is asking for, since it is **NOT** there.

Comment: Does compiler compile header file separatelly from a corresponding cpp file that we can think about cpp file as about separate cimpilation unit?

Comment: The compiler does **not** compile a header file. When you `#include "headerfile.h"`, all you are doing is instructing the preprocessor to **COPY and PASTE** that header file into the cpp file. Yeah, that's all it's doing. C/C++ unfortunately has quite an ancient system for this...

Comment: If compiler dos not compile a header file then in my case every class implementation falls in the same corresponding compilation unit. And therefore it is not the case of separate compilation units. See please my code.

Comment: well you see, `tf1.o` and `tf2.o` are two separate translation units. And they do not have *full* mutual knowledge of each other. And when you use that template class in `tf2.cpp`, what the compiler sees is the content that can be found in `tf1.h1`. Now does `tf1.h` have the full definition of the template class you're using? And, does `tf1.cpp` know in any way that you're instantiating the class with that specific type in `tf2.cpp`?

Comment: But please note that there is no file tf2.cpp first. And the second, tf2.h knows all about tf1.o because it includes tf1.h

Comment: your file names have confused me.
I'm going to edit my answer to show you why it does not work.

Comment: Yes, Seems you have to read my code more carefully. And please note that error happens for A1 and not hapens for A2 while they both are absolutelly identical. Why so?

Comment: @OlegG I have updated my answer. Note the reason only `A2` have problems because in `tfmain.cpp` you are not creating an instance to `B1`, which instantiates `A1`, so the linker had no need to link code to `A1`'s methods. It only needed to link to `A2`'s methods.

Comment: Yes. Now it is totally clear. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't put your templated functions definitions inside of `.cpp` files, you have to put them in your header files. This is a weird limitation of templates.

It has to do with the fact that templated versions of your functions are only generated when they are used. Thus, you can't pre-compile a templated function, because it hasn't been used yet, so it doesn't generate everything.

Comment: But compiler does not protest against it. So why have I to think that I do something wrong?

Comment: Well, you got a linker error. That should probably be a red flag.

Comment: Generally speaking you're obviously right - if I get linker error then I do something wrong. Yes, captain. But compiler does not protest and allows me to make mistakes which are not mistakes from its point of view. Weird. Definetly weird.

Comment: I mean, you're not really "making a mistake", from the compiler's point of view. The compiler never sees that you have used the template, so it doesn't generate any code. Thus, only when you get to linking, the compiler gets confused about why you never defined them. Like I said, it's just a bit of a weird/annoying thing that you have to do to get templated functions to work.

Comment: @OlegG From the compiler's point of view, there is nothing wrong with calling a template when some or all definition of its methods is not in the scope.
It's the same with using a normal class.
From a grammar point of view, there is absolutely nothing wrong with it.
The only problem is how the compiler generates code when it comes to template.
My answer below tries to explain this.

Comment: @OlegG : You can define the templates in another compilation unit and link them in, but you have to explicitly instantiate them in the other compilation unit.  So until link time, the compiler does not know you are screwing up.  Now, maybe you should get a warning, because few people intend to do this, but such a warning ends up being redundant with the shortly-arriving linker error, so...

Comment: Guys, please, show me what and how in my case `method()` and `m()` are not in the scope. And why it happens only for A2 and not for A1?

Answer (score 0):

Xymostech answered your question, but I do not agree that this limitation is weird. ;)  [This should clarify this matter for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Well, it's only weird in the sense that it doesn't work the same as other function declarations/definitions. I know what you mean, though.