# Unresolved Externals with Templates

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get “unresolved external symbol” errors when using templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456713/why-do-i-get-unresolved-external-symbol-errors-when-using-templates)

I'm trying to implement a generic Queue using templates.

I have the following code in my header:

```
template<class Item>
class Queue{
protected:
    struct linked_list;
    int size;
public:
    Queue();
    Queue(Item T);
};
```

I have a Queue.cpp:

```
template<class Item>
Queue<Item>::Queue()
{

}
template<class Item>
Queue<Item>::Queue(Item T)
{

}
```

but every time I compile, I get a linker error because of unresolved externals.

I reinstalled VS2012 twice (thinking the linker was broken), but the problem keeps appearing.

I read that there is some problem with the function implementations being in a separate file when working with templates, but I haven't seen any solution except putting the implementation in the header.

Is there a more elegant way to do so?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099

Answer (score 2):

Template doesn't support `a definition is provided elsewhere and creates a reference (for the linker to resolve) to that definition`

You need to use `the inclusion model`, put all Queue.cpp definition into Queue.h file. Or in the bottom of Queue.h

```
#include "Queue.cpp"
```

Comment: Really? Usually when working with headers, all I do is create a header and a source with the same name and include the header in the source, and it works just fine.

Comment: but this is template, it's different

Answer (score 0):

Template declarations must be included in your source code in their entirety. If you want to split them, one way I prefer to use is:

on the bottom of queue.h:

```
#define QUEUE_H_IMPL
#include "queue_impl.h"
```

and in queue_impl.h

```
//include guard of your choice, eg:
#pragma once

#ifndef QUEUE_H_IMPL
#error Do not include queue_impl.h directly. Include queue.h instead.
#endif

//optional (beacuse I dont like keeping superfluous macro defs)
#undef QUEUE_H_IMPL

//code which was in queue.cpp goes here
```

Actually now after I've looked at it you don't need an include guard at all if you `#undef QUEUE_H_IMPL`.