# Unresolved external symbol on operator++ in template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get “unresolved external symbol” errors when using templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456713/why-do-i-get-unresolved-external-symbol-errors-when-using-templates)

I am making a linkedList.  I am using an external iterator.  The Iterator class is a template, and I am implementing my methods in the Iterator.h.

Here is the template:

```
#pragma once

#include "Node.h"

 namespace list_1
 {

template<typename T>
class Iterator
{
public:
    Iterator<T> (Node<T> *np);
    void operator++();
    bool is_item();
    T operator* ();

private:
    Node<T>* n;
};

template<typename T>
Iterator<T>::Iterator (Node<T> *np)
{

}

template<typename T>
void Iterator<T>::operator++()
{

}

template<typename T>
bool Iterator<T>::is_item()
{
    return false;
}

template<typename T>
T Iterator<T>::operator* ()
{

}
 }
```

I get this error message when I try to compile: `1>list_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall list_1::Iterator<double>::operator++(void)"`

Plus about seven other similar errors in the whole project.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Or is it something else I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `list_1` a class or namespace?  Is the `Iterator` class definition inside or outside the `list_1` definiton?  Is the `operator++` definition inside or outside the `list_1` definition?

Comment: I don't see an `inline` in front of that `operator` implementation, so i clearly isn't in the same **header file** as the template declaration. Unless this is all in a *single* source file, you're not going to get what you want without explicit instantiation.

Comment: Sorry, Iterator is in the namespace list_1.  `template<typename T>
void Iterator<T>::operator++()` is also in list_1.

Comment: @WhozCraig: `inline` doesn't do much at all on a template function or member function of a class template.

Comment: @aschepler you're correct, but for non-template code it is the thing that raises duplicate-references, and thus I always use it on any out-of-class member impl, even template ones. You are most-correct, however.

Comment: why is operator++ returning void?

Comment: I can't repro this when the file mentioned that contains all of this is a *header file*, and lord knows [i've tried.](http://ideone.com/Xvs6rg). Clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: Maybe try a `make clean` or `Rebuild All` option.

Comment: The code you have shown us is correct. You'll get a correct answer if you provide complete code that shows your error.

Comment: My code is in the .h not the .cpp.  This question is not similar to the  "duplicate" question.  The titles are similar, but the idea is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your error message correctly, you Iterator takes `Node<T>` as input, however you are applying `double` to it which is not applicable. To support `non-Node<T>` type, you need to specialize `Iterator<T>`.

```
public: void __thiscall list_1::Iterator<double>::operator++(void)"
                                         ^^^^^
```