# "unresolved external symbal" on template class

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors, external-dependencies

I have worked on this same problem for three days, I can't do anything about it.  Please Help!!

This is not a duplicate of a question with a similar name.  The name is similar, but the problem is completely different.

May have something to do with External Dependencies is what I am told.

I am posting all of my code, and if I need to post more info please ask!

`list_test.cpp` This does more, but this is where it messes up.

```
 #include <cctype>       // Provides toupper
 #include <iostream>     // Provides cout and cin
 #include <cstdlib>      // Provides EXIT_SUCCESS
 #include "list.h"  // With value_type defined as double
 #include "Node.h"
 #include "Iterator.h"
 using namespace std;
 using namespace list_1;

 int main( )
 {
     list<double> test;
 }
```

`iterator.h`

```
 // Template CLASS PROVIDED: Iterator 

 #pragma once
 #include "Node.h"

 namespace list_1
 {
template<typename T>
class Iterator
{
    public:
    Iterator<T> (Node<T> *np);
    // precondition: is_item is true
    // post condition n points to the next item in the list
    void operator++();
    // precondition: 
    // postcondition: returns true if there is a valid item
    bool is_item();
    // precondition: is_item == true
    // postcondition returns data that n is pointing at
    T operator* ();

    private:
    Node<T>* n;

};

template<typename T>
Iterator<T>::Iterator (Node<T> *np)
{
    n = np;
}

template<typename T>
void Iterator<T>::operator++()
{
    assert(is_item( ) == true);

    n = n->next;
}

template<typename T>
bool Iterator<T>::is_item()
{
    return (n->data != NULL);
}

template<typename T>
T Iterator<T>::operator* ()
{
    assert(is_item( ) == true);

    return n->data;
}
 }
```

`Node.h`

```
 #pragma once

 namespace list_1
 {
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node<T> *next;

    // Constructor
    // Postcondition: 
    Node<T> (T d);
};

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T d)
{
    data = d;
    next = NULL;
}
 }
```

`list.h`

```
 #include "Node.h"
 #include "Iterator.h"

 namespace list_1
 {
template <typename T>
class list
{
    public:
        // CONSTRUCTOR
        list();
        // postcondition: all nodes in the list are destroyed.
        ~list();
        // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        //postcondition: entry is added to the front of the list
        void insert_front(const T& entry);
        //postcondition: entry is added to the back of the list
        void add_back(const T& entry);
        // postcondition: all nodes with data == entry are removed from the list
        void remove_all(const T& entry);
        // postcondition: an iterator is created pointing to the head of the list
        Iterator<T> begin(void);
        // CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        // postcondition: the size of the list is returned
        int size( ) const;
    private:
        Node<T>* head;
};

template <typename T>
list<T>::list( )
{
    head = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
list<T>::~list()
{

}

template <typename T>
void list<T>::insert_front(const T& entry)
{
    // head = new node(entry, head);
}

template <typename T>
void list<T>::add_back(const T& entry)
{

}

template <typename T>
void list<T>::remove_all(const T& entry)
{

}

template <typename T>
Iterator<T> list<T>::begin(void)
{
    //Iterator<T> traverse( );
    //return traverse;
}

template <typename T>
int list<T>::size( ) const
{
    int size = 0;
    Node<T> *tempPoint = head;

    for (tempPoint = head; tempPoint != NULL; tempPoint = tempPoint->next)
    {
        size ++;
    }

    return size;
}
 }
```

Here is the error message:

```
 1>------ Build started: Project: CS2420LinkedList, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
 1>list_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall list_1::list<double>::~list<double>(void)" (??1?$list@N@list_1@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
 1>list_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall list_1::list<double>::list<double>(void)" (??0?$list@N@list_1@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
 1>C:\Users\KyleYas\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CS2420LinkedList\Debug\CS2420LinkedList.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: FWIW, it is probably not a good idea to give your class the same name as an STL container and import both your namespace and the `std` namespace through a `using` directive. Have you tried a different name? Just as an experiment...

Comment: (Btw, I am assuming you tried to cleanup everything and rebuild. If you did not, try that as well)

Comment: ...and so `using namespace` finds its next victim. Tutorial writers who recommend it should be tied to a lamppost and forced to listen to a computer voice reading g++ template error messages.

Comment: "*I am posting all of my code, and if I need to post more info please ask!*" - We don't want more of your code, we want **less**. You would have received an answer by now if you had posted the smallest possible complete test case that demonstrates the problem. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more info.

Comment: Your test program works fine for me with g++ 4.7.2. What compiler are you using?

Comment: What happens when you remove the "using namespace std" line?

Comment: @Rob Well I did post less code here and got no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514379/unresolved-external-symbol-on-operator-in-template.  I resorted to posting all my code.  Thanks for the interest, I've tried all of it.  I'm using Visual Studio 2012 C++ Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the answers!  I found the problem.  I had two of the same list.h files in the External Dependencies, so I just deleted it and it compiled.  I don't know how it happened, I guess I set up my program incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't necessarily defend its use but I don't think your problem is the `using` statement. I can't see any reason to have collision when you don't `#include <list>`. That would be:
 `error C2872: 'list' : ambiguous symbol...`. 
From what the message says I would start by making sure that `list.h` is where it's supposed to be.

Also, you can always reference VS error codes like the [LNK2019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you're getting and check the examples against your issues.